# Button inside asp:panel is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ajax extender in my aspx page.

I want to make the button do something in code behind when is pushed but my button inside the panel doesn't work.I created another button outside the panel and wrote the same thing to do and is working.

### This is my button inside the panel:

```
<ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">
<Header><a href="#" class="href">Adauga titlu</a></Header>
<Content>
<asp:Panel ID="UserReg" runat="server" DefaultButton="but">
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" width="500px"/>    
<br /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="but" Text="Adauga Titlu" />    
</asp:Panel>
</Content>
</ajax:AccordionPane>
```

This button is not working but the other button outside is working and they both do the same thing.Can you provide a solution?

Comment: remove `DefaultButton="but"`in `asp:Panel` and try it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are simply missing the OnClick attribute, like this:

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="but" Text="Adauga Titlu" OnClick="but_Click" />
```

Comment: if you answer with a question, then it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: that was my problem..I was missing the onclick.But strange I doubled clicked it and the onclick event didn't show up and I had to put it manualy...strange

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the Asp ScriptManager?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx